# Possible to have Local Notifications push on iPhone using a php screen that sends an alert?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4

Possible to have Local Notifications push on iPhone using a php screen that sends an alert?
i would like the iphone to call a php script and see for any changes if it did change then send a local notification to the user.

Comment: Then that wouldn't make it local anymore. Plus please tag your question correctly, local notifications don't exist in [iphone-sdk-3.0].

Answer (score 0):

Not possible. The App needs to be open to register local notifications. If the php is on a server push notifications could be used though.